# Passing multiple arguments with (**kwargs) wildcard to Parent Class in Multiple Inheritance - Python

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, keyword-argument

Help, This is a test for a Car Dealership where I am passing on attributes from `Cars` and `Customers` into the `CarDealership` class. I want to practice using `**kwargs` for when I have a lot of variables.

I am practicing multiple-inheritance and using `**kwargs` to pass potentially multiple arguments to the parent class, the inheritance logic is actually wrong here since the `Customer` is not a `CarDealership` etc.

My issue though is why am I getting an error when trying to pass the arguments to the parent class from the `Ferrari` class.

Here is my Python code:

```
class CarDealership:    
    def __init__(self, customer_id=None,car_id=None,clean=True,sold=False):
        self.customer_id = customer_id
        self.car_id = car_id
        self.clean = clean
        self.sold = sold
        
    def new_car(self, sold = False, car_clean = True,**kwargs):
        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)
        self.car_id = car_id
        self.brand = brand
        self.color = color
        self.car_type = car_type
        self.price = price
        
    def customer_Add(self, **kwargs):
        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)
        self.customer_name = customer_name
        self.customer_id = customer_id

    def customer_purchase(self, customer_id, car_id, price):
        if sold:
            print("Car sold!")
        else:
            self.sold = True
        self.customer_id = customer_id
        self.car_id = car_id
        self.price = price 
        
    def clean(self, car_id):
        self.car_clean = True

    def __del__(self):
        print("Car Sold")


#cars
class Car(CarDealership):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)
        self.car_id = car_id
        self.brand = brand
        self.color = color
        self.car_type = car_type
        self.car_clean = car_clean
        self.sold = sold
        self.price = price
        data={"car_id":car_id,
              "brand":brand,
              "color":color,
              "car_type":car_type,
              "price":price,
            }
        super().__init__(car_id)
        super().new_car(**data)
        
class Customer(CarDealership):
    def __init__(self, **kwards):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)
        self.customer_id = customer_id
        self.customer_name = customer_name
        data={"customer_id":customer_id,
              "customer_name":customer_name
              }

class Ferarri(Car):
    def __init__(self):
        data={"car_id":1,
              "brand":"Ferrari",
              "color":"red",
              "car_type":"Racing",
              "price":1000000
              }
        super.__init__(**data)

cars = [Ferarri()]

for car in cars:
    arguments=[car,car.color,car.brand,car.car_type,car.sold,car.price]

    string = "{}, color:{}, brand:{}, car_type:{}, sold:{}, price:{}".format(*arguments)
    print(string)
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/stazc/Desktop/AI/Python/Apps/carDealershipTry02.py", line 80, in <module>
    cars = [Ferarri()]
  File "C:/Users/stazc/Desktop/AI/Python/Apps/carDealershipTry02.py", line 78, in __init__
    super.__init__(**data)
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' of 'super' object needs an argument
```

I am passing on the arguments from the `Ferrari` class to the `Car` class but it seems I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Subclassing represents an is-a relationship. A car is not a car dealership. A customer is not a car dealership either.

Comment: You need to actually call super: `super().__init__(**data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `super().__init__()` not `super.__init__()`